# How to judge a determinant equals non-zero in cryptography?

Tags: signature

In the paper [1,p5], the authors construct a matrix to find out $n$ solutions of a equation set as follows:

[image]

where $c_i$ is generated by the adversary, $c$ is picked by the simulator. Note that $c^i$ means different forgeries instead of exponent.

My question is, they find out $n$ solutions iff the determinant equals non-zero, but they don't prove why the determinant equals non-zero. There is no need to prove it?

(I'm not true this is a crypto problem or not, it seems more like a math problem?)

[1] Liu, J. K., Au, M. H., Susilo, W., & Zhou, J. (2014). Linkable ring signature with unconditional anonymity. IEEE Transactions on Knowledge and Data Engineering, 26(1), 157–165. https://doi.org/10.1109/TKDE.2013.17

Comment: Let $A$ be an $n\times n$ matrix. Then the system $Ax=b$ has exactly one solution vector $x$ with $n$ entries iff $\det A \neq 0$, that is iff $A$ is invertible. This is a basic result of linear algebra.

Comment: @SEJPM Yes, I know it. My question is how to prove $A\neq 0$? The authors didn't give an explaination.

Comment: From the context you provide it's not clear to me that the matrix is invertible, and I don't have access to the paper since it's behind a paywall. So we need either more context please or a free link to the paper.

Comment: @eins6180 Thanks for concerning. I'm sorry I'm not sure if it is legal to send you the paper. May I have your contact? Whichever is OK.

Comment: I'm sorry but this is really not how it works. If you're uncomfortable to provide a free link to the paper you need to provide more context. But having this discussion in private prevents everyone else to contribue and learn from it.

Comment: @eins6180 I mean I send the paper to you privately. All universities can access the paper, then the discuss is still helpful for others.

Comment: They do say "up to" $n$ solutions.  Perhaps they say this so that they don't exclude the case of $\det(A)=0$.

Comment: @rikhavshah Sounds interesting, but if $|A|=0$, there is not a solution.

Comment: That's not necessarily true.  $|A|=0$ means there are either 0 or infinitely many solutions.  Without more information about their construction, I can't say much more.

Comment: @rikhavshah Thanks anyway. Please contact me #p1gd0g if you have telegram.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the matrix as follows

$$
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & c_1^{(1)} & c_2^{(1)} & ... & c_n^{(1)}\\
1 & c_1^{(2)} & c_2^{(2)} & ... & c_n^{(2)}\\
... & ... & ... & ... & ...\\
1 & c_1^{(n+1)} & c_2^{(n+1)} & ... & c_n^{(n+1)}
\end{pmatrix}
$$

If all $c_i$ for $i\in[n]$ are determined after $H_Z$ query, we can say that they are generated from $c=H_Z$ which is randomly picked by $\mathcal{B}$. Then we know that the determinant of this matrix $det(M)=0$ with only negligible possibility.

Answer (score 0):

For linear system $Ax = \beta$ with a vector on $n$ unknowns $x$, $A$ is the Vandermonde matrix, produced with powers of $c_i$. For such a matrix, determinant is a product of $(c_i - c_j)$, and so is non-zero for different $c_j$ in the set of field elements.

Comment: Note that $c^i$ means different forgeries instead of exponent.